# Performance issue while merging data to a delta lake

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, azure-synapse, delta-lake

The solution that I'm working on involves a delta lake table that had a full load in the beginning of around 110gb and now there's incremental load daily of around 1-2mb. The first time I loaded the 110 gb CSV file in delta lake, it took around 3 hours and created a single parquet file in the delta folder of around 3gb. But the problem now is that everytime we try to merge data to it, even if it's just 1-2mb, it still takes around 3-4 hours to merge. Can I optimise it since the current performance of merge won't work for the solution. I've read about partitioning the data but not sure how it'll help as the source table has a combination of 4 columns as a primary key and a timestamp column.

Currently the source df I'm creating before merge is using:

```
sdf = spark.read.csv(incremental_csv_path, sep='^A',header=True, multiLine='True')
```

And for the merge to delta lake, I'm using(conditions_list being the string of those 4 columns):

```
if  (DeltaTable.isDeltaTable(spark, delta_table_path)):
    delta_table = DeltaTable.forPath(spark, delta_table_path) delta_table.alias("existing").merge(
    source = sdf.alias("updates"),
    condition = " AND ".join(conditions_list)
     
    ).whenMatchedUpdateAll(
    ).whenNotMatchedInsertAll(
    ).execute()

else: 
 sdf.write.format('delta').save(delta_table_path)
```

I'm fine with full load taking longer duration but any method to reduce the merge time will be really helpful.

Comment: That seems expected. Merge will read the complete existing delta table, and then merge the incremental data based on the condition. If you are sure that the incremental data only has new records and no update/upserts, then the [append mode](https://docs.delta.io/0.3.0/delta-batch.html#append-using-dataframes) would be ideal

Comment: That's the issue, incremental data also contains updates to previous entries so append won't be ideal.

Comment: You need to partition it, maybe use a data column or columns that you are merging on. Delta engine can use partition elimination so it will only access those files in the partition that it needs to update

Comment: So what would be a better approach towards partition? Use all 4 columns that make up the primary key or use one of those columns that has the least cardinality? I'm open to suggestions but my only concern is if partitioning based on one or more PKs for a file of over 100gb will lead to creation of way too many parquet files in the delta folder and lead to memory issues while merging. Again, I'm new to this field and might be way off so any correction or help is really appreciated.

Comment: Yes you're right. Partition column should be the one with least cardinality. In your case the incremental data should belong to as few partitions of the existing delta as possible so that [partition pruning](https://kb.databricks.com/delta/delta-merge-into) is useful

Comment: Thanks for the input, I feel maintaining the historical data with daily merge might not be the best idea in delta lake and I should move to azure SQL, merge performance is far better over there because of indexing. Thanks again and please let me know if there's anything else that can be done that I might have missed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the data having 1 billion records.

[image]

You need to do partition on column having least cardinality.
To check that you use `distinct` on those 4 columns separately and decide on which column to use.

Below are the 1000 distinct values in those 1 billion rows, that means it creates 1000 partition.

[image]

Similarly check out those 4 columns in your data which are feasible for partition.
Below is the code used for partitioning.

```
df.write\
    .format("delta")\
    .mode("overwrite")\
    .partitionBy("par")\
    .save("/random/source/")
```

Now creating a new updates records.
Here, i am creating 1000 record with unique `par` having values `1,2,3,4`.

```
sdf = spark.range(1000).withColumn("id", (rand() * 30000000 * 2).cast(IntegerType()))\
.withColumn("par", col("id")%5)\
.withColumn("ts", current_timestamp())
display(sdf)
```

[image]

After that merge is done on `id`  column.

```
from delta.tables import *
conditions_list=["existing.id = updates.id"]
delta_table_path="/random/source/"

if (DeltaTable.isDeltaTable(spark, delta_table_path)):
    delta_table = DeltaTable.forPath(spark, delta_table_path)
    delta_table.alias("existing").merge(
    source = sdf.alias("updates"),
    condition = " AND ".join(conditions_list)
    ).whenMatchedUpdateAll(
    ).whenNotMatchedInsertAll(
    ).execute()
else:
    df.write\
        .format("delta")\
        .mode("overwrite")\
        .partitionBy("par")\
        .save("/random/source/")
```

It took **1.91** minutes to merge files.

[image]

Now add partition condition like below inside your `conditions_list` to improve performance.

```
update_cols = [i[0] for i in sdf.select("par").distinct().sort("par").collect()]
par_val = ','.join(map(str,update_cols))
conditions_list=["existing.id = updates.id"]
conditions_list.append(f"existing.par in ({par_val})")
conditions_list
```

[image]

Here I am getting distinct new values of `par` column, in your case it is the column you done partition on it. So that it checks the files in these partitions only.

Now running merge statements.

Before running if i check the record give no results.

[image]

Now merge command took only **4.14** seconds, that is it's almost 28 times faster.

[image]

After running merge command.

[image]

So my suggestion is do partition on column which is feasible to your
cluster memory and less cardinality.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Jayashankar, I tried creating a new column based on year of data and partitioning on that, it's already around 10 times faster than earlier. Will try adding partition condition to condition list to check if it improves merge speed further. Thank you so much again.